# Cannot install TinyTex from R

Tags: r, latex, sudo, darwin, tinytex

I cannot get tinytex to install via RStudio. I am running RStudio 1.1.463 on MacOS X 10_11_6 (El Capitan).

I have installed the tinytex package. I am trying:

```
library(tinytex)
install_tinytex()
```

I receive the error message:

```
ls: /Users/(myname)/Library/TinyTex/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy: No such file or directory
```

I have tried simply searching the error on Google, but I don't really understand anything that comes up in the results (which start talking about something called sudo and different things with terminal) to know whether its relevant to my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue and made a post on RStudio community including this post as well as my solution to the problem so far (linked below).

To summarize my solution:

- Make hidden folders visible on Mac
- Locate /Users/(myname)/Library/TinyTex/bin/
- Rename universal-darwin folder to x86_64-darwinlegacy
- Run tinytex installation

https://community.rstudio.com/t/tinytex-installation-recent-issue/102861

I'd like to see a more elegant (and explainable) solution to this!

Comment: This actually worked even though a new universal-darwin folder got generated. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @apshinyn worked for me when helping a student but I used a very slight modification and a little more detail. I'm not able to edit @apshinyn solution, however, so am reposting my version that worked for us:

1. GO TO Library/TinyTex/bin:

   - OPTION 1: Go to the Finder; Click on the GO menu; Select GO TO FOLDER (Or hit Command-Shift-G) and type: `~/Library/TinyTex/bin`
   - OPTION 2: Go to the Finder; Click on the GO menu; Hold down the OPTION key; Select LIBRARY; Open the `TinyTex` folder and then `bin` folder.
2. RENAME: Change the name of the folder `universal-darwin` to `x86_64-darwinlegacy`
3. INSTALL TINYTEX: In R or RStudio, in the Console or command line run `tinytex::install_tinytex()`
4. CHECK TINYTEX: In R or RStudio, in the Console or Command line run: `tinytex::is_tinytex()`. If you get `TRUE` the installation worked.